# *ngIf not trigger inside service with eventListener

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `label` that render by `*ngIf` like this:

```
<label for="file-8" id="upload-area" *ngIf="isAllowUpload">
    <input type="file" id="file-8" accept="image/*"  style="display: none;" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
    <div class="empty-image-input">
       <img src="assets/static/media/plus-sign.svg" alt="icon" width="18" height="18">
    </div>
</label>
```

onFileChanged function:

```
onFileChanged(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    this.onUpload();
}
```

onUpload function:

```
private onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const file of this.files) {
      formData.append("file", file, file.name);
    }
    const self = this;
    this._service.uploadImage(formData)
    .pipe(finalize(() => {}))
    .toPromise()
    .then((info: any) => {
         this.isAllowUpload = false;
         this.cdRef.detectChanges();
         var container = document.getElementById('image-container');
         container.innerHTML += `
             <label id="image0">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <button type="button" id="delete-image"> </button>
                    <img src="` + info + `">
                </div>
            </label>
        `;
        document.getElementById('delete-image').addEventListener('click', function () {
           this.isAllowUpload = true;
           this.zone.run(() => this.isAllowUpload = true)
           this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        })
    })
}
```

That mean when service finish load data, a html content is created and append to `<div id="image-container">`. `<label>` DOM is hidden because `isAllowUpload = false`(it still work). After that, I created `addEventListener` that catch event when click `<button id="delete-image">`.
When button is clicked, event fired and `isAllowUpload` changed value but view not re render `<label id="upload-area">`.

I try to use `detectChanges` and `ngZone` but it still not work.
Is there any way to toggle this DOM element. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance ?

Comment: Why do you convert the observable into a promise instead of just piping into a map?

Comment: And the fact that you fetch an element outside of the component and modify it is very much against the core idea of Angular's component isolation

Comment: @Prince here stackblitz editor: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idoxul)

Comment: @ShamPooSham : thanks for your suggest, I just follow the app structure design before. I'll improve it after fixed this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Added my answer, i agree with shampoosham that you can do it angular way more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with HTML in your stackblitz instance. You are overriding the content of HTML with a string and your actual binding is no more there.

Keep the div separate where you are appending the data. Please see below:

```
<div>
    <!-- wrap div where you want to append image. -->
    <div class="property-content" id="image-container">
    </div>
    <label for="file-8" id="upload-area" *ngIf="isAllowUpload">
                  <input type="file" id="file-8" accept="image/*"  style="display: none;" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
                  <div class="empty-image-input">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/plus.png" alt="icon" width="18" height="18">
                  </div>
                </label>
    <p *ngIf="isAllowUpload">allow upload</p>
</div>
```

Please find the working link in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xld2in

Comment: Thank you!. It work. I don't think I need to separate appended data and *ngIf content.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following method.

```
this.cdRef.markForCheck();
```

Comment: Follow the document in https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef. There are no function markForChange. Only markForCheck() and checkNoChanges

Comment: thanks for pointing out the type please do that change and see it its working